# Matplotlib plotting shapes on a graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to draw a shape on a graph. Here is my code...

```
    def graphData(self, stock):
    stock_file = Company.objects.get(ticker_name=stock)
    stock_file = stock_file.data
    stock_file = stock_file.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("'","")
    stock_file = re.sub("(([^,]*,){5}[^,]*),\s*","\\1\n",stock_file)
    file_name = "/home/philip/PycharmProjects/stockmarket/static/stock_data/data_file.txt"
    file = open(file_name, "w")

    points = [[2, 4], [2, 8], [4, 6], [6, 8]]
    line = plt.Polygon(points, closed=None, fill=None, edgecolor='r')

    file.write(stock_file)
    file.close()
    date, closep, highp, lowp, openp, volume = np.loadtxt(file_name, delimiter=",", unpack=True, converters={ 0: date_converter })
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = plt.subplot(1,1,1)
    ax1.plot(date, openp)
    ax1.plot(date, highp)
    ax1.plot(date, lowp)
    ax1.plot(date, closep)
    ax1.grid(True)
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(10))
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))
    for label in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
        label.set_rotation(90)
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=.10, bottom=.22, right=.93, top=.95)
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Stock Price')
    plt.suptitle(stock+': Stock Price')
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig("/home/philip/PycharmProjects/stockmarket/static/graph.svg")
```

The two separate lines starting with `points = ...` and `line = ...` are the code I added to try and draw the shape. Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1):

Call `ax.add_patch(line)` to add the `Polygon` to the axes, `ax`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(2016)

points = [(2, 4), (2, 8), (4, 6), (6, 8)]
line = plt.Polygon(points, closed=None, fill=None, edgecolor='r')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(1,1,1)
ax.add_patch(line)

date = np.linspace(0, 7, 100)
openp = (3*np.sin(8*date)/date)+6
ax.plot(date, openp)
ax.set(xlim=(1,7), ylim=(3,9))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm. Still doesn't seem to work. Could you try this with my code to verify whether its a system error?

Comment: Okay I've got it to plot this now, however it plots it instead of my other data rather than over it.

Comment: What is the relationship between the `points` coordinates and the `date` and stock price values? For instance, where should the point `(2, 4)` lie on the graph, if the `date`s range from say `2000-1-1` to `2016-1-1`?

Comment: If I change the (2, 4) value to a value I know is on the graph I still can't see the shape.

Comment: Is `date` a list of `datetime.datetimes`? Or does `date_converter` change them to floats? Please post a runnable example so we can see reproduce your problem.